# Moving files in the sdcard

Tags: android, file-io

I have been trying to move files within the sd card but to no avail: Here is the code:

```
try {
            File sd=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // File (or directory) to be moved
            String sourcePath="mnt/sdcard/.Images/"+imageTitle;
            File file = new File(sd,sourcePath);
            // Destination directory
            String destinationPath="mnt/sdcard/"+imageTitle;
            File dir = new File(sd,destinationPath);

            // Move file to new directory
            boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(dir, file.getName()));
            if (!success) {
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File moved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

I dont know wasup.Will appreciate the help.

Comment: What's not working? Logcat? Stacktrace?

Comment: And some more notes. Try to not cach generic exceptions. And your file path is not beginning from root.

Answer (score 12):

First: If you've gotten the external directory, there is no need to add it to the beginning of your `sourcepath` and `destinationpath`

Second, the destinationPath seems unnecessary as it looks like you just want to move it to the sdcard's root folder.

It should be

```
File sd=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// File (or directory) to be moved
String sourcePath="/.Images/"+imageTitle;
File file = new File(sd,sourcePath);
// Destination directory
boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(sd, imageTitle));
```

Comment: note that the destination folder needs to exists. File.mkdirs can come in handy for this