# Save clicked images into custom folder(Preferably internal to the app ) instead of gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to incorporate the camera functionality into the application. I am able to save pictures into the custom folder, but the problem is that the images are getting saved into camera folder(where the camera pics get saved) also. So there is a duplicate images for every image that I take. I don't want that. Following is the code:

```
public class PhotoIntentActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;

    private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";

    private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;

    /* Photo album for this application */
    private String getAlbumName() {
        return getString(R.string.album_name);
    }

    private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
                .getExternalStorageState())) {

            storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory
                    .getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName(), getApplicationContext());

            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                        Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name),
                    "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }

        return storageDir;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX,
                albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }

    private void setPic() {

        /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
        /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

        /* Get the size of the ImageView */
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        /* Get the size of the image */
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
        int scaleFactor = 1;
        if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
            scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);
        }

        /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        System.out.println(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        switch (actionCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
            File f = null;

            try {
                f = setUpPhotoFile();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(f));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                f = null;
                mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        } // switch

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }

    private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            setPic();
            galleryAddPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }

    }

    Button.OnClickListener mTakePicOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        mImageBitmap = null;

        Button picBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIntend);
        setBtnListenerOrDisable(picBtn, mTakePicOnClickListener,
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
        } else {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                handleBigCameraPhoto();
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    // Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);

        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY,
                (mImageBitmap != null));

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView
                .setVisibility(savedInstanceState
                        .getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? ImageView.VISIBLE
                        : ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
     * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
     * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
     * found, this method returns false.
     * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The application's environment.
     * @param action
     *            The Intent action to check for availability.
     * 
     * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
     *         responded to, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

    private void setBtnListenerOrDisable(Button btn,
            Button.OnClickListener onClickListener, String intentName) {
        if (isIntentAvailable(this, intentName)) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        } else {
            btn.setText(getText(R.string.cannot).toString() + " "
                    + btn.getText());
            btn.setClickable(false);
        }
    }


public final class FroyoAlbumDirFactory extends AlbumStorageDirFactory {

    @Override
    public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName, Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),albumName);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can delete the file once it's saved in your custom file. If you're not sure of the name of the file the camera took, you can look at the time stamp or, if you're willing to go crazy, you can use `FileObserver` to wait for the file to be finished writing before deleting it (if concurrency is an issue and something bad happens.)

After doing some research, I found that that answer is posted here:
[Double save image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563570/double-save-image)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is saved under application cache directory which only accessible from you re application context `context.getCacheDir()`

Or use this class
and call `ExternalStorage.getSDCacheDir(context,"dirname");`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;


public class ExternalStorage {
// Convention for external storage path used by Android 2.2.
private static final String EXT_STORAGE_ROOT_PREFIX = "/Android/data/";
private static final String EXT_STORAGE_ROOT_SUFFIX = "/files/";

private static StringBuilder sStoragePath = new StringBuilder();

private static final String ALTERNATE_SDCARD_MOUNTS[] = { "/emmc", 
        "/sdcard/ext_sd", // Newer (2011) HTC devices (Flyer, Rezound)
        "/sdcard-ext", // Some Motorola devices (RAZR)
        "/sdcard/sd", // Older Samsung Galaxy S (Captivate)
        "/sdcard/sdcard" // Archos tablets
};

/**
 * Create given directory on sd card application cache Directory.
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param dirName
 * @return created cache directory file, if not created return null.
 */
public static File getSDCacheDir(Context context, String dirName) {
    File cacheDir = null;

    // Check to see if SD Card is mounted and read/write accessible
    if (android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(android.os.Environment
            .getExternalStorageState())) {
        // Get the directory on the SD card to store content
        // Attempt to use getExternalFilesDir() if we are on Android 2.2 or newer
        // Data stored in this location will auto-delete with app uninstall
        Method getExternalFilesDirMethod = null;
        try {
            getExternalFilesDirMethod = Context.class.getMethod(
                    "getExternalFilesDir", String.class);
            cacheDir = (File) getExternalFilesDirMethod.invoke(context,
                    dirName);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // Android 2.1 and earlier - use old APIs
            cacheDir = buildCacheDirPath(context,
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    dirName);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            cacheDir = buildCacheDirPath(context,
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    dirName);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            cacheDir = buildCacheDirPath(context,
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    dirName);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            cacheDir = buildCacheDirPath(context,
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    dirName);
        }
    }

    if (cacheDir == null) {
        // Attempting to find the default external storage was a failure.
        // Look for another suitable external filesystem where we can store
        // our crap
        for (int i = 0; i < ALTERNATE_SDCARD_MOUNTS.length; i++) {
            File alternateDir = new File(ALTERNATE_SDCARD_MOUNTS[i]);
            if (alternateDir.exists() && alternateDir.isDirectory()
                    && alternateDir.canRead() && alternateDir.canWrite()) {
                cacheDir = buildCacheDirPath(context, alternateDir, dirName);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Attempt to create folder on external storage if it does not exist
    if (cacheDir != null && !cacheDir.exists()) {
        if (!cacheDir.mkdirs()) {
            cacheDir = null; // Failed to create folder
        }
    }

    // Fall back on internal cache as a last resort
    if (cacheDir == null) {
        cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator
                + dirName);
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    return cacheDir;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways

1. **Camera Intent**.
2. **Custom camera**.

You are using Camera Intent.

> new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

**MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE**- Intent action type for requesting an image from an existing camera application.

**MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT** - This setting requires a Uri object specifying a path and file name where you'd like to save the picture

How To save [media file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media)?

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
  private Uri fileUri;

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
  }
```

Please follow the above instruction correctly to avoid such duplicate.

2nd option is You need to use [Custom Camera](http://www.mydoople.com/android-camera-example).

Please Read this full [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) to understand about the camera function.

**Hint:**

In your **startActivityForResult()** write the code to [move the picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588364/moving-files-in-the-sdcard) from **camera folder** to your **Custom folder** instead of saving images in your custom folder.

Hope this may give you some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the image from camera folder after saving this image in custom folder